# R - convert string (chr) to data frame name and apply function to multiple data frames

Tags: r, readfile, lapply

I am trying to read csv files (whose file names contain certain characters) from my local directory and apply a function to all data sets.

Here's how I read the files with file names starting with "Answer_Worksheet":
(In the directory C:/Users/User/Downloads, there are files named Answer_Worksheet_19, Answer_Worksheet_20, Answer_Worksheet_21, etc.)

```
answercsv <- list.files(path="C:/Users/User/Downloads",
    pattern="Answer_Worksheet+.*csv",full.names=FALSE)
answernames <- substr(answercsv,1,nchar(answercsv)-4)

#read files
for(j in answernames){
    ansfilepath <- file.path("C:/Users/User/Downloads",paste(j,".csv",sep=""))
    assign(j, read.table(ansfilepath,header=TRUE,sep=",",na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ") ))
}
```

And one example dataset named "Answer_Worksheet_19"

```
ID  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8
491 10  3   1   5   3   1   10  2
491             4               
480 10  3   1   33  3   1   10  /
488 4   3   1   5   3   1   10  5
488 3           6               
482             5   3   1   10  5
482 10          33      1       
492 4   3   1   33  6   2   10  5
488 10          33              
488                             
492 10                          
492                 3   1       
509 10  3   1   33  3   1   10  5
498                             
500 10  3   1   33  3   1   10  5
498                             
500                             
503 10  3   1   33  3   1   10  5
498 10  3   1   33  6   1   10  5
```

And the function to be applied:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

answeranalysis<-function(data){

    #subset "Q" columns
    Q<-data[,grep("Q",names(data))]

    for(i in 1:NCOL(Q))
    {
        #histogram (frequency)
        count<-count(Q,i)
        colnames(count)[1]<-"ans"
        ggsave(ggplot(data=na.omit(count),aes(x=reorder(ans,-freq),y=freq))+geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="dodgerblue")+geom_text(aes(label=freq),vjust=0,size=7)+xlab("Answers")+ylab("Freq")+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15,face="bold"),axis.title=element_text(size=16)),file=paste("C:/Users/User/Downloads/answer",i,".png",sep=""))

    }

}
```

Basically there are two problems I have encountered:

1. In order to apply the function answeranalysis to data sets, I've tried to do:

   markstimelist<-as.list(markstimenames)

   lapply(names(markstimelist),function(x) answeranalysis(markstimelist[[x]]))

but apparently it doesn't work because the items stored in the lists are only the names of the data sets (strings, chr) but not the data sets themselves. 
Thus, how can I access the data sets with the strings?

2. With the current answeranalysis(), there will be n png barcharts generated (n=number of columns that contain 'Q'), namely answeri.png, where i is the question number.

But if I apply the function to multiple data sets, how do I add the worksheet number to the names of the png barcharts?

e.g. answeranalysis(Answer_Worksheet_19) ---> there will be 8 png barcharts generated, namely worksheet19answer1.png, worksheet19answer2.png, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To answer question (1):

You can use the function eval, which evaluates the text as if it was a variable.
`parse` usually parses a file, but you can specify text, like here.

`EVAL<-function(z){eval(parse(text=z)))}
lapply(names(markstimelist),function(x) clustering(EVAL(x))`

## For question 2:

You can add a for loop and save it this way:

`for(i in 1:length(worksheet)){
ggsave(paste("worksheet",i,"....png",sep = ""))`